# What's the best practice for displaying a personal website url in a resume?

Tags: style, formatting, websites, resume

Like most veteran coders in the IT industry, I have an out-of-date website that I use to link to different activities I'm involved with online, like Twitter and Stack Overflow. Up until now, I haven't gotten around to working the address into my resume, but now is as good a time as any.

So what is the best practice for an IT worker to display a website in their resume?

Is it better for the eyes to center the url at the top?

Should it be above or below a horizontal rule?

Should it be close to, perhaps above or below an email address?

What's the most common, acceptable way for a personal website to be include in a resume?

Comment: This is less of a question about writing, and more about design and current business practice. It's not off-topic here, but it'd be more on-topic at [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/). It's too old to migrate there, but they'd be happy to get more questions like this. (I asked.)

Comment: While it maybe "less of a question about writing", it is nonetheless a question about writing, even if it overlaps with other categories.

Comment: Oh, it is about writing. Didn't mean to imply otherwise. You'd just get better answers on the Workplace site, is all.

Comment: @NeilFein - Sure, sorry I'm just used to having to be reflexively defensive about questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the purpose of including that URL in the first place. If it is a "here's more info about me" site, I'd say put it with your name, address, and email.  If it is an example of work you did for a particular employer, then then that block of your employment section makes sense.  If it is for a portfolio site, maybe front and center, under your name, at the top of the resume.

I would not use a horizontal rule on a resume.

Answer (score 6):

My resume has, centered up top in the header: my name | email | phone. If I were going to put in my URL, I would add another pipe and put it in, probably omitting the `http://`

Alternatively, I sometimes put it in my cover letter/intro email if I feel it's relevant. E.g.:

```
Regards,

First Last
Phone
URL
```

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question, but do you literally put **| pipes** in your resume, or are you saying that they are evenly spaced on the top row?  Also do you have the first and last elements aligned against the horizontal margins?

Comment: If the resume is in Word, I wouldn't object to pipes. There's only so much you can do in Word for formatting. I wouldn't align those elements against the margins; I would center the entire block.

Comment: Yeah the pipe character. I like it better than dashes, semi-colons, plain whitespace, etc. It has a clean look, and its purpose (separation) is clear. The entire header block is centered.

Comment: This is best.  Put it at the end of your other contact into.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about doing it with

- my name aligned (justified?) to the **top left corner**
- my website minus `http://` aligned to the **top right corner**
- remaining contact information below this aligned to one side or the other in left, right, left sequence.

Feel free to upvote or downvote my answer so that I can get a feeling for whether or not this is generally a good idea.

Comment: It sounds a bit cluttered.  Definitely leaving off the http:// is smart. I'd keep everything neat and organized,  with your contact info and your URL in one block, either on the left (preferred) or right. My 2 cents.

Comment: Just remember that, in most of cases, the www won't make any difference so, you remove the http:// and the www.